Get the latest 5 files from a folder using the OneDrive connector inside power automate flow
I have the following action to "List the Files in Folder" :-

Now how I can only get the latest (based on the modified date) 5 files?
I used this formula to get the id of the latest file: -
last(sort(outputs('List_files_in_folder_2')?['body/value'], 'LastModified'))?['Id']

But how I can get the 5 latest files? i cannot find a way to do LastN()?

I don't know how to do it in Power Automate, or what the exact formulas would be, but if I were doing it through a REST/oData API, I would flip it and do $orderby=LastModified desc&$top=5

After sorting, you could get the latest 5 files info by using length() and skip() functions.
[Compose 2]:
length(outputs('Compose'))   

[Last 5 Files Info]:
skip(outputs('Compose'), sub(outputs('Compose_2'),5))



Please note that by default List files in folder does not return all the files from the OneDrive folder. You may need to increase Pagination Threshold in Settings of this step

worked well, thanks
